# overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet when changing markers, line still stay

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using this plugin overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet.

Let's imagine I am showing 3 markers and all of them have the same position. this plugin as it says will show only 1 marker. and when I click on that marker, 3 markers will appear and they will be connected with lines. Something like this:

[image]

**Question 1)** If you are looking at that image, you will see that lines are a little bit wrong. It should be exactly connected between two markers, but there's a kind of overlap. why is that?

---

Let's take a look at another image:

[image]

**Question 2)** After some time, I made some markers invisible (their opacity became 0). Now it turns out that even though there's 1 marker as shown on the image, when clicked, it shows lines connected to nowhere. Why is that and how do I make those lines not appear?

Comment: Even on the official demo page for this plugin, it doesn't seem to work very well. For clustering markers i use [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)

Comment: so you don't use overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet at all and what you use does the same thing as overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet this plugin, but more beautifully right?

Comment: Basically, yes. But it's up to you to choose which one you prefer. I don't know about overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet, though.